# JDBC: fetchSize actually used by driver or fetch counts (roundtrips)

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-data, dynatrace

Env: Oracle 19c, ojdbc8-19.3.0.0, JDK 17, Spring boot 3 web, k8s

Context: we have an spring-web-rest-app doing merely queries against database and producing JSON responses. The queries are done with dynamically set fetchSize on spring's JdbcTemplate. The value is picked from a pre-configured set of values. There are times that we see via Dynatrace that database fetch counts don't match our expected fetch counts, given the fetchSize we set. Such cases lead to degraded response time. (Solved by increasing memory after consulting Oracle JDBC Memory Management)

We now want to monitor this as **metrics** and get notified as soon as the ratio of actual fetch counts to expected fetch counts exceeds a threshold.

Question: we know fetchSize we set for each query. How could we find out:

1. the actual fetchSize used by driver?
2. or fetch counts (roundtrips) (how does Dynatrace do it)?
3. other ways to get this done?

Comment: What's the fetch size that you're seeing?

Comment: We didn't see any fetch size. During analysis with Dynatrace we saw the fetch count. The fetch count was too high given the fetch size we set, say, page size is 5K, we set fetch size to 1K. We expect fetch count to be no greater than 5. But we actually saw it was 1.25K, which hints at a fetch size of 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the actual fetch size by querying `v$sql` (if you have multiple child cursors and want to see them all in aggregate, you can use `v$sqlarea` instead). Identify the `sql_id` of your query either by finding it with `v$sql.sql_fulltext` or by seeing it active for your session in `v$session` or recently active in `v$active_session_history`. Once you have the `sql_id`, simply watch the `fetches` vs. `rows_processed` to get your fetch size:

```
SELECT child_number, rows_processed/NULLIF(fetches,0) rows_per_fetch
  FROM v$sql
 WHERE sql_id = 'cr9n9traa800b';
```

As these numbers are cumulative, your calculation will be an average since the cursor was loaded in the shared pool. To get minute-by-minute averages you'd need to capture this info every minute and compute the deltas on both columns before doing the division. You can also get this info for every hour (or more or less, depending on the AWR interval set in your database) already time-lapsed and delta'd for you by querying `dba_hist_sqlstat`:

```
  SELECT s.begin_interval_time,
         ss.rows_processed_delta/NULLIF(ss.fetches_delta,0) rows_per_fetch
    FROM dba_hist_sqlstat ss,
         dba_hist_snapshot s
   WHERE ss.snap_id = s.snap_id
     AND ss.sql_id = 'cr9n9traa800b'
   ORDER BY 1
```

But as that won't have information until the next AWR flush it isn't very useful for trial-and-error testing.

*Note*: if your database is RAC (multiple instances) you'll want to change all `v$` views to `gv$` views to see across all instances. If you get an error that the table does not exist, you may need to ask your DBA for "`SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`" privilege to be able to run these queries.

Comment: We can definitely build on this e.g. a counter-metrics on "fetches". Together with known fetchSize and pageSize we can calculate the ratio. However, it'll be cooler, if we can do this by querying some kind of JDBC metadata, like on the ResultSet we get back.